# Arduino And Bluetooth LE AK1595 IC

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, uart, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

reacently started a new project - to add Bluetooth to Atmega2560 chip.

I'm familiar with NRF52 and HC-05 bluetooth modules. But wanted to experiment with AK1595 BLE IC, because i didn't need an extra MCU and its smaller and cheaper. And UART protocol suits my needs also.

So i made the circuit as in datasheet. But i cant get it to advertise.

As i understand when AK1595 chip powers on  - reset pin should be low, and SET1 - low also. After all is powered on i need to make reset  pin high, few microseconds later SET1 pin high. Than switch TXON pin on (from low to high), and than it should start to advertise? What I'm missing?

Using BLE app on mobile to check it.

AK1595 - [Datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.akm.com/kr/ko/products/communication-ic/ble-beacon/ak1595/&ved=2ahUKEwiHu4q74ZbtAhXGpYsKHXx_BekQFjAAegQICBAC&usg=AOvVaw1mDp0ecugD6tdg8SGXOCik&cshid=1606069380212)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The AK1595 is of course an MCU just like all of the others.  Given you have provided no meaningful debugging information and no details of what you have done to try to configure it, this reduces to simply a question about the *usage of a product*, and those are not on topic here.  If you really want to pursue this, you should start by finding a manufacturer example of how to correctly operate it, and try that *unmodified* before you strike out on your own.  Otherwise, you're probably better off with one of the several choices known and supported in the Arduino community.

Comment: It doesnt have dedicated MCU inside that chip. Could you please tell, what is meaningful debuging info?

Comment: It most certainly *does* have an MCU inside that chip!  What do you imagine is running the bluetooth stack and carrying on the other end of whatever conversation you might (and probably need to be) having over the serial UART connection?  So far there's nothing to indicate that you are doing (or even aware of) what would be required to make this chip advertise, and you have done nothing to determine its own status.  If you had actual program code that attempted to configure the chip, and documented unexpected responses that might almost be an on topic question; what is here now is not.